# How to display only first two object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, reactjs

Here, I have stored four objects in an array. I want to display only the first two objects in the `ReactDOM.render` method.

Currently, all of the items are displayed. I am looping through the array with the jQuery `map` function.

How can I display only the first two objects?

```
var data = [
    {id:1, content:'test1'},
    {id:2, content:'test2'},
    {id:3, content:'test3'},
    {id:4, content:'test4'}
];

var UserList = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        var Users = this.props.data.map(function(el, i){
            return <li key={i}>{el.content}</li>;
        });
        return (
            <ul>{Users}</ul>
        );
    }
});
ReactDOM.render(
  <UserList data={data} />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Comment: No, you are not using jQuery `map` function. You are using native `Array.map` (vanilla Javascript)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`.slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice),

```
<UserList data={ data.slice(0, 2) } />
```

[`Example`](https://jsfiddle.net/ofb7paks/)

Comment: this is what i want. Thanks bro